# PHP foreach loop that creates four colums on flexbox

Tags: php, css, foreach

I'm trying to make something like a flexbox with CSS and PHP. The idea is to upload .jpg images to a folder and then sort them into four columns equally. My current approach is to count the total number of files in the folder, divide by four and with that create indices for a foreach loop to iterate and put the images into the columns. I need it to [look like this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_image_gallery).

Later on I'll have to make a popup on each of these images which should bring some basic HTML/CSS thing. Not sure if that's something to take in mind for this particular case.

This is my (incomplete/not working) code:

```
<?php
$fi = new FilesystemIterator("../../showoff_images", FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
printf("There were %d Files", iterator_count($fi));
$fi = iterator_count($fi);

#Divided $f1 by four to get the number of items in columns
$fby4 = intdiv($fi,4);

#Create start index for each image
$f0 = 0;
$f1 = $fby4-1;
$f2 = $fby4*2-1;
$f3 = $fby4*3-1;
$f4 = $fby4*4-1;

#CHECK THE INDEX FOR THE IMAGES. START AT 0 AND START ITERATING WITH THE $fn VALUES FOR THE FOLLOWING FUNCTION!
  #Iterates images
  $directory="../../showoff_images/";
  $images=glob($directory . "*.jpg");
  $lazyload = "lazy";
  $measure = "100%";
  $distance = "20px";
  
  foreach($images as $image=>$value) {
    if($value > 4) continue;
      ++$value;
      echo 
      "
      <h2 style = padding-top= ".$distance." padding-bottom= ".$distance." padding-right= ".$distance."  padding-left= ".$distance."></h2>
      <img src=" .$image." loading =". $lazyload ." height=".$measure." width=".$measure.">
      ";
      
      
      #++$f0;
      
  }

?>
```

Really appreciate your help and glad to be joining the forum!

Comment: So you have an array of images, let's call them A through Z. Do you want your HTML to be linearly A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H... or are you trying to do something like A, E, I, M, B, F, J, N?

Comment: The best would be to have it something like this:

A|B|C|D
E|F|G|H|
I|J|K|L|
M|N|O|P

etc

Comment: Hey, answer doesn't display properly, but the idea is to have ABCD on first row, EFGH on second row, etc.

Comment: I'm not seeing you do anything special like wrapping each "row" of four item in a div, so I think you can just echo and let flex/grid take care of the rest. If you are going to wrap them, then I think [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) will help you. https://3v4l.org/HpTSH. And hopefully some day the browsers will natively support [Masonry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Masonry_Layout)

Comment: Thank you! The link you provided seems to be a good option. I'll test it later today with hopefully good results.

Comment: @ChrisHaas So I tested it and itpartially worked on my end. This is my code https://imgur.com/a/UBDYovx and this is the rendered output on the browser: https://imgur.com/a/4II0oMI You see, it's not being wrapped inside the row class. What could be wrong here? I'm fairly new to PHP (In reality this is the first time I'm using it)

Comment: Your closing div appears to be inside the loop and it should be outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Comment to answer*

You should be able to use [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) for this, which will allow you to break your array up into sub-arrays.

Here's a sample, not really bound to your data but it should make sense.

```
$letters = range('a', 'z');
$rows = array_chunk($letters, 4);
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo '<div>', PHP_EOL;
    foreach($row as $letter) {
        echo $letter, PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</div>', PHP_EOL;
}
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/HpTSH

Comment: Thank you! Until now I noticed I had a wrong bracket. This has been really helpful

Comment: Hey, I noticed that when adding more images, let's say 18 images with an array chunk = 4, the last images will be created on a new column and looks very wrong. The main issue is that some images are horizontal, and others are vertical, so at the bottom of the website images don't look quite on place. What would you suggest to fix this? Setting a max height could fix it?

Comment: That really depends on your CSS. I'm personally a big fan of CSS `display: grid` and things like `object-fit` but depending on your layout you might need to do different things. It might help to post a new question with what you are trying, what it looks like and what you want it to look like. If you do that, PHP really shouldn't be part of the problem, it should be an HTML and CSS only problem at that point, but you can make a note here and I might be able to weigh in on it.

Comment: So I finally got it working with a mixture between PHP to load all the files and using Masonry as you suggested. You've been really helpful, thank you!